# Ruby on Rails Assets: Links not working properly when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, turbolinks

When you press enter in the address bar or refresh the page, it works like charm but as soon I click on a link in the navigation bar, some or most of the assets wont load. I already added `"data-no-turbolink" => true` to the `link_to` but no success.

This is my **`application.html.erb`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">

    <title>Rev</title>

    <!-- FAVICON AND APPLE TOUCH -->    
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-180x180.png">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="mstile.png">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#94ccdf">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#94ccdf">

    <!-- FONTS -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Playfair+Display:400,400i" rel="stylesheet">

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="main container">

      <!-- HEADER -->
      <header id="header">

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">

              <!-- LOGO -->
              <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.html">
                  <%= link_to(image_tag("arrow-down.png", :alt => "arrow", :size => "150x150"), "/") %>
                </a>
              </div><!-- LOGO -->

            </div><!-- col -->
            <div class="col-sm-9">

              <!-- MENU -->
              <nav>

                <a id="mobile-menu-button" class="waves" href="#"><i class="custom-icon-menu"></i></a>

                  <ul class="menu clearfix" id="menu">
                    <li class="megamenu">
                    <li class="<%= is_active?(root_path) %>"><%= link_to "Home", root_path, :"data-no-turbolink" => true %></li>
                    </li>
                    <li class="megamenu">
                      <li class="<%= is_active?(menu_team_path) %>"><%= link_to "Meet Team Derrick", menu_team_path, :"data-no-turbolink" => true %></li>
                    </li>
                    <li class="megamenu">
                      <a href="#">New Patient Center</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="megamenu">
                      <a href="#">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

              </nav>

            </div><!-- col -->
          </div><!-- row -->
        </div><!-- container -->

      </header><!-- HEADER -->

      <%= yield %>

    </div><!-- MAIN CONTAINER -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**`application.scss @imports`**

```
 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";
 @import "plugin";
 @import "fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
 @import "animations/animate.min.css";
 @import "calendar/beatpicker.min.css";
 @import "counters/odometer-theme-default.css";
 @import "fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css";
 @import "custom-icons/css/custom-icons.min.css";
 @import "custom-school-icons/css/custom-school-icons.min.css";
 @import "custom-interface-icons/css/custom-interface-icons.min.css";
 @import "custom-office-icons/css/custom-office-icons.min.css";
 @import "revolutionslider/css/settings.css";
 @import "revolutionslider/css/layers.css";
 @import "revolutionslider/css/navigation.css";
 @import "owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css";
 @import "ytplayer/css/jquery.mb.ytplayer.min.css";
```

**`application.js requirements`**

```
//= require jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require viewport/jquery.viewport.js
//= require menu/hoverIntent.js
//= require menu/superfish.js
//= require fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js
//= require revolutionslider/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js
//= require revolutionslider/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js
//= require revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js
//= require revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.carousel.min.js
//= require revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js
//= require revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js
//= require revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.migration.min.js
//= require revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js
//= require revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js
//= require revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js
//= require revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js
//= require owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js
//= require parallax/jquery.stellar.min.js
//= require isotope/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js
//= require isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js
//= require placeholders/jquery.placeholder.min.js
//= require validate/jquery.validate.min.js
//= require submit/jquery.form.min.js
//= require charts/jquery.easypiechart.min.js
//= require counters/jquerysimplecounter.js
//= require counters/odometer.min.js
//= require statistics/chart.min.js
//= require instafeed/instafeed.min.js
//= require twitter/twitterfetcher.min.js
//= require ytplayer/jquery.mb.ytplayer.min.js
//= require countdown/jquery.countdown.min.js
//= require animations/wow.min.js
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**`Gemfile`**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
#WOW-Rails
gem 'wow-rails'
#Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does your console log say when you click a link?

Comment: Also, is your syntax correct? Try: `<%= link_to("Home", root_path, "data-no-turbolink" => true) %>` Note the added parentheses and the removal of the colon.

Comment: @MarsAtomic When I hit enter or refresh at the address bar, I receive a 200 status code and then a 304 on each of my assets. Page loads fine. When I click on any of the links in the navigation bar, I get a 200 but thats pretty much it. Page loads without most of its assets. Especially the revolution slider at the top.

Comment: Changed the syntax, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `method: "get"` with `link_to`.

Try below code in your nav bar:

```
<ul class="menu clearfix" id="menu">
  <li class="megamenu">
  <li class="<%= is_active?(root_path) %>"><%= link_to "Home", root_path, :"data-no-turbolink" => true, method: "get" %></li>
  </li>
  <li class="megamenu">
    <li class="<%= is_active?(menu_team_path) %>"><%= link_to "Meet Team Derrick", menu_team_path, :"data-no-turbolink" => true, method: "get" %></li>
  </li>
  <li class="megamenu">
    <a href="#">New Patient Center</a>
  </li>
  <li class="megamenu">
    <a href="#">About Us</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Could you explain why the method has to be called again?

Comment: Using `method: get` effectively creates a form on every click, then submits it, which is not really what you want. To disable Turbolinks on your menu, remove `:"data-no-turbolink" => true, method: "get"` on each link, then add `data-turbolinks="false"` to the `<ul>`